# How to detect when device has resumed from sleep mode

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect when the android system has resumed from sleep mode, but has not turned on the screen?  My service does not need to acquire any wake locks, but does need to know when the device has been woken up by another process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect whether the phone is in sleep mode in the code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359762/how-to-detect-whether-the-phone-is-in-sleep-mode-in-the-code)