# android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON doesn't work as a receiver intent filter

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to get a BroadcastReceiver invoked when the screen is turned on. In my AndroidManifest.xml I have specified :

```
                <receiver android:name="IntentReceiver">
                    <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
```

However it seems the receiver is never invoked (breakpoints don't fire, log statements ignored). I've swapped out SCREEN_ON for BOOT_COMPLETED for a test, and this *does* get invoked.

This is in a 1.6 (SDK level 4) project.

A Google Code Search revealed this, I downloaded the project and synced it, converted it to work with latest tools, but it too is not able to intercept that event.

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#_8L9bayv7qE/trunk/phxandroid-intent-query/AndroidManifest.xml&q=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON

Is this perhaps no longer supported?

Previously I have been able to intercept this event successfully with a call to Context.registerReceiver() like so

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // ... 
  }
}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
```

However this was performed by a long-living Service. Following sage advice from CommonsWare I have elected to try to remove the long-living Service and use different techniques. But I still need to detect the screen off and on events.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Following sage advice from CommonsWare
>   I have elected to try to remove the
>   long-living Service and use different
>   techniques.

Actually, I believe my advice was more of a light blue... :-)

> But I still need to detect the screen
>   off and on events.

There are certain events that Android does not want to start up new processes for, so the device does not get too slow from all sorts of stuff all having to run at once. `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is one of those. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off) for light blue advice on that topic.

So, you need to ask yourself, "Self, do I really need to get control on those events?". The core Android team would like it if your answer was "no".

Comment: Thanks CW. It would have been marvelous if there was some kind of warning at runtime or in the documentation about ACTION_SCREEN_ON being impossible to catch. I file this one under 'gotcha'.

Comment: Yeah, I think they documented that `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` -- the quintessential example of this phenomenon -- behaves this way, but they definitely skipped this one. If you search for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` in the source code (e.g., via Google Code Search) and find its use in `PowerManagerService`, you'll notice the flag indicating registered-receiver-only is set.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best example I've found http://androidexample.com/Screen_Wake_Sleep_Event_Listner_Service_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=91&aaid=115

Answer (score -1):

Actullay i was faceing this issue but i resolve it succeessfully

1) start service from your main activity

```
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
    startService(i);
```

2) register reciver in service class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();



    // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReciever();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

3) Done