# how to check in my android app when switch on mobile device?

Tags: android, service

i want to get the event when mobile is switched on in my application.
so, how i handle/get switched on event of mobile in my app, is it necessary to run my app in background?

can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the discussion in this thread:

[Is it possible to write an Android broadcast receiver that detects when the phone wakes up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577318/is-it-possible-to-write-an-android-broadcast-receiver-that-detects-when-the-phone)