# Is it a good idea to have a service just to register for intents?

Tags: android

I have an application that listens for screen off, and user present intents.  Since you cant register to receive screen off intents from the manifest, I am registering them in a service.

Do I really need to have a whole service to ensure that I always get notified of when the screen shuts off, and the user unlocks the phone?  Seems really wasteful :-(

The code I use in my service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "Service created.");
    // register receiver that handles user unlock and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider what you are broadly trying to do, and a different way to do it.

Yes, the only way to monitor the events is to be actively registered.  This is very intentional, because they are a very tempting thing for applications to think they want to be told about, and ending up with a bunch of apps having to be launched each time the user turns their screen on or off would end up with a really bad user experience.

Given that, I can tell you right now that there is no way you can *guarantee* that you will see these events, besides using a service that is always running *and* has used startForeground() to prevent itself from being killed.  Obviously, this is not something you want to do unless your app is doing something the user very deliberately cares about having running for them when they decide it should be.

So...  what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is very intentional.  The app I am building is very open about why it needs to do this, and what it performs on userlogin is a very trivial task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a broadcast receiver class. A broadcast receiver can be a stand alone part of an application.

Comment: So even if my application isnt running, and there isnt a service running, I will still receive these intents?

Comment: Yeah. A broadcast gets sent to every intent registered in the manifest to accept that broadcast. Your application can ONLY consist of a broadcast receiver if that's what you want. You don't need an application, a service, or anything else.

Comment: Can I register the broadcast receiver in my main activity?  (For intents described above that you cant register for in a manifest)

Comment: Seems you cant do this either, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575242/android-intent-action-screen-on-doesnt-work-as-a-receiver-intent-filter

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realize there were specific broadcasts you couldn't listen to at certain times.

Answer (score 2):

Action_User_Present can be registered in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

> Since you cant register to receive screen off intents from the manifest

Are you sure about that? The documentation does not describe that limitation, whereas it does for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, `ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED`, and `ACTION_TIME_TICK`.

Please use a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` if at all possible.

Comment: You can't register for them.  This is very deliberate, since having a bunch of apps that need to run each time you turn on/off the screen would quickly lead to a really cruddy experience.

Comment: Any chance the documentation could be updated to reflect this?

Comment: @Christopher: I filed an issue on b.android.com about it, ~10 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is some core android code.

```
mUserPresentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
mUserPresentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING
 | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT);
```

and

```
mScreenOnIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
mScreenOnIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
mScreenOffIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
mScreenOffIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
```

We should register filter programmatically when core send with  "FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY" Flag.