# How to restart the Service Automatically in android?

Tags: android

I have started a service in Activity.Now, if i force close the activity then automatically the service is also force stopped.Is there any way to restart it automatically.?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Using Alarm manager you can try or broadcast receiver you can try..

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.How to restart the service through Broadcast receiver.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552927/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-a-service-just-to-register-for-intents

Comment: @SreenathReddy: return START_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT from onStartCommand() method in your service..

Comment: What do you mean saying 'I force close the activity'? Closing activity normally won't stop any services they are stopped by using either stopService from activity or stopSelf from the service itself.

Comment: @imrankhan:Thanks for your reply.But i have already included that in my code. check this code                                      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
 {
  handleFunction();
  System.out.println("IN onStartCommand.......");
     // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
     // stopped, so return sticky.
     return START_STICKY;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the `onStartCommand()` method by returning the `START_STICKY` or `START_REDILIVER_INTENT`, but it's your responsibility to stop the service by calling `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should return START_STICKY from onStartCommand in your service. This will make sure Android restarts your service after being killed. See the link bellow.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

This will not deliver again the original intent. If you also need that return START_REDELIVER_INTENT.

These are also explained in the Android blog.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html