# Unable to register BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, preferenceactivity

I am unable to register my BroadcastReceiver. Whenever I try to execute my code its showing "Unable to register receiver" in logcat.

Here is my code where I am registering my receiver:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    private Button button;
    ListPreference lp;
    private Context context;
    private long duration;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        context = this;
        lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("autoduration");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, BackService.class);
        lp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                String newSelection = newValue.toString();
                int index = lp.findIndexOfValue(newSelection);
                stopService(intent);
                if (index == 0) {
                    duration = 15000;
                } else if (index == 1) {
                   duration = 12000;
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    duration = 10000;
                } else if (index == 3) {
                    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
                    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
                    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new ScreenReceiver();
                    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
                }
                intent.putExtra("duration", duration);
                startService(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

and this is my receiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static boolean screenOn = true;
    private static final String TAG = "ScreenReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
             screenOn = true;
             Log.e(TAG, "I am receiver");
        } else {
            screenOn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the code and made it correct. Its working now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your register code could be invoked 2 and more times before unregister will happen. Are you sure it's not the issue?

Comment: may be it is the issue but if i remove unregister statement then it is giving me an error "Are you missing unregisterReceiver?" :(

Comment: No, you should not remove unregister statement. Instead you have to be sure your register code invokes only once (since you unregister it only on destroy). But in your code register will happen any time your 4th preference will change and it's incorrect. You have to be sure you don't register receiver that has already been registered.

Comment: actually the problem was i declared 2 receivers one global and one local and i registered only the local one which i defined in onPreferenceChange so that is why it is giving me an error that receiver did not register because global one was still unregistered. :D Thanks for your help :)

Comment: but now my problem is different. It registerd the broadcastreceiver but i cant see my log msg when i turn on the device screen. Strange...!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? [android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON doesn't work as a receiver intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575242/android-intent-action-screen-on-doesnt-work-as-a-receiver-intent-filter)

Comment: i have gone through this thread thats why i register my receiver in java code but its still not working. any other solution?