# sendBroadcast() - Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT

Tags: android, android-studio, android-broadcast

Im trying to manually send a broadcast in Android Studio

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

does not work.

Error code:

```
Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
```

Is there any way to send a Broadcast or execute the receiver manually?

thx :)

Comment: Don't know if this will help you, but I had once experienced a similar issue and got help from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469431/permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-in-android

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619696/broadcast-receiver-for-action-user-present-action-screen-on-action-boot-complete