# androidmanifest multiple receivers

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have two receivers in manifest file. One is working one is not. Can I have multiple receivers in manifest ?

```
<receiver android:name=".services.MobileViaNetReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".services.SessionManager">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

UPDATE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

ACTION SHUTDOWN IS WORKING FOR ME. Following is a code for SessionManager

```
public class SessionManager extends BroadcastReceiver{
Date timeOff;
Date timeOn;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     

    if( "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        timeOff = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    } 

    if( "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Functions.logout(context);
    } 

    if( "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        timeOn = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        long diffInMs = timeOn.getTime()-timeOff.getTime();

        // convert it to Minutes
        long diffInMins = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diffInMs);

        if ((int) (diffInMins) > 15) {
            Functions.logout(context);

        } else {
            Log.i("MobileViaNetReceiver", "User still active");
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: But SCREEN_OFF and SCREEN_ON also not working for me

Answer (score 0):

OK, as you definitely get SHUTDOWN intent,  your broadcast receiver IS working.   But it does not mean that SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF are actually being sent  and delievered to your application.  Here is some explanation about this condittion:

[android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON doesn't work as a receiver intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575242/android-intent-action-screen-on-doesnt-work-as-a-receiver-intent-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following inside of the intent filter for your receiver that is not working.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```