# Background broadcastreceiver is not launching

Tags: android

In manifest xml:

```
<receiver android:label="BGTasksBroadcast" android:name=".BGTasksBroadcast">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Log", "BROADCAST RECEIVER " );
}
```

When I launch the app I am not seeing the log "BROADCAST RECEIVER ".

Comment: I need to call the service in the background. So i am using broadcast reciever to call that. But i am not seeing any log placed in Broadcast reciever. I dono how to debug this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you lock and unlock your device di you see it ?

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.REBOOT
```

are different from app launch.

Android does not seem to support manifest-registered receivers for cases where they really do not want to start up a new process. For example, you will see the same effect with the battery info actions (e.g., BATTERY_LOW). (cc CommonsWare) you have to start them from the code, see here: [android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON doesn't work as a receiver intent filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575242/android-intent-action-screen-on-doesnt-work-as-a-receiver-intent-filter)

Comment: Ya but i am not seeing the logs even if i close the simulator and run once again..

Comment: You use reboot, if you need boot you should use: ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: SCREEN_ON is enough to call the broadcast reciever rite?

Comment: i am not seeing the log when i lock or unlock the simulator

Comment: Android does not seem to support manifest-registered receivers for cases where they really do not want to start up a new process. For example, you will see the same effect with the battery info actions (e.g., BATTERY_LOW). (cc CommonsWare) you have to start them from the code, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575242/android-intent-action-screen-on-doesnt-work-as-a-receiver-intent-filter

Comment: Then what is the best approach for calling the service in the background even if my app not launched?

Comment: I would use ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED to start the others from java code.

Comment: BOOT_COMPLETED is working fine now. After installing the app the user needs to reboot the device for activating to my service?