# Android detect phone lock event

Tags: android

I want to be able to detect the phone lock event. When my app is running, if I press the red button (call end button/power button), the phone gets locked and the screen goes blank. I want to be able to detect this event, is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a Broadcast Receiver

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

and

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
```

Related: Read **CommonsWare's Answer** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off).

Comment: For the record -- lock off/on is not the same event as screen off/on.

Comment: Screen Off will occurr even of tje screen goes off when making a phone call

Comment: Here's an example of this not catching the lock screen: on Android 5, if I switch users, the OS goes to the lock screen without turning the screen off.

Comment: Can we disable SCREEN_OFF event when making a phone call ?

Comment: Another issue with this is: if the screen automatically turns of after the phone is left idle, the phone might not lock until 5 seconds afterwards. The broadcast is sent on screen off rather than on phone lock.

Comment: Locking can occur without screen_off event, for example, if device is locked via device admin.

Answer (score 37):

Alternatively you could do this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        isScreenOn = powerManager.isInteractive();
    } else {
        isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
    }

    if (!isScreenOn) {

        // The screen has been locked 
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to add a permission to the application manifest for this one?

Comment: Tried this, and no need to add permission

Comment: I think this only check whether screen-on or not, not check the lock. This can mix with FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, so the screen-off only when you lock screen.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn()

what about check unlocked ? (not screen-on)

Comment: the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462843/android-what-happens-when-device-is-unlocked

Comment: User isInteractive () instead of isScreenOn() for API 20 onwards

Comment: How would I check if the device is locked, when in live wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

Register a broadcast with IntentFilter `filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)`

works pretty well even screen is turned on/off

Comment: No. It is not reliable. Does not get fired on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Koltin format of Robert's solution.

```
 override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
        val powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val isScreenOn: Boolean = powerManager.isInteractive
        
        if (!isScreenOn) {
            // The screen has been locked 
            // do stuff...
        }
    }
```

I am assuming Kitkat version is quite old already.