# How to reveal that screen is locked?

Tags: android, sleep, power-off

In my application I need to know when device is locked (on HTC's it looks like short press on "power" button). So the question is: which event is triggered when device is locked? Or device is going to sleep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should extend `BroadcastReceiver` and implement `onReceive`, like this:

```
public class YourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            //screen has been switched off!
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just have to register it and you'll start receiving events when the screen is switched off:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
appBroadcastReceiver = new AppBroadcastReceiver(yourActivity);
registerReceiver(appBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: If you're wanting to check if the device is locked, you could use the method from [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260794/how-to-tell-if-device-is-sleeping/4261021#4261021). Unfortunately there's no broadcast for the device locking, but I find it useful to be able to check if it's locked or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better way:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

Comment: Did you try isDeviceLocked  for Android 5.1 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#isDeviceLocked()?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, in-case you want to trigger some action when your app is at the **foreground**:

You could use the event called **onResume()** to trigger your own function when your app takes the spotlight from a previously resting state, i.e, if your app was at the background(paused/minimized...)

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    //call user-defined function here
}
```

Comment: No, it's not suitable, since onResume() called everytime when activity starts, so there's no clue either it comes after sleeping or just creating

Comment: yup. definitely. just a suggestion :)