# For api < 16: How to detect if PIN/password/pattern is required to unlock phone?

Tags: android, locking, unlock, keyguard

I already know these two cases:

1) for devices using api >= 16, one could just use the method `isDeviceSecure()` from `KeyguardManager` and that would return true if any locking mechanism is used on the device (pattern, passcode, password, etc.)

2) for devices using api <= 15, one could do something like `if (Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED) == 0)`, but that would only check for screen locking pattern (not passcode, password, etc.)

So my question is how would I check for any screen locking mechanism on devices using api <= 15?