# How to tell if user is on lock screen from service

Tags: android, service, locking, screen

I have simple service that running in the background and I just want to know when the user is on the lock screen or not, that way I know when to start a process.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check out [a similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260794/how-to-tell-if-device-is-sleeping). Use `KeyguardManager` to check if the device is locked.

```
KeyguardManager kgMgr = 
    (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean showing = kgMgr.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

Comment: btw, this only works if the user actually has a lock screen set. if a lock screen isn't set and the user "locked" the screen (by pressing the power button), then this will not detect that state.

Comment: permission or something, do i need it to be declared as well @mopsled?

Comment: @Daren What if lock screen is not set ... How can I know if the screen is locked or not ???!!!!

Comment: @ahmedghanayem If lock screen is not set, the screen cannot be locked (it can only be OFF).

Comment: @ahmedghanayem use kgMgr.isKeyguardLocked() to check if the user is on the lock screen (whether or not the pin code or password is set). Newer devices can be set to automatically "unlock" in certain conditions such as Home wifi, Bluetooth proximity, face unlock, etc. I have tested it using face unlock. (Tip: for testing, use a Handler to check the boolean every 1000ms).

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to firstly register a BroadcastReceiver in your Service to listen when power button is pressed (turns screen on/off):

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    registerReceiver(lockScreenReceiver, filter);
}

final BroadcastReceiver lockScreenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
            if (LockScreenHelper.isScreenUnlocked(getBaseContext())) {
                // what does this mean?
                Log.i(TAG, "screen is unlocked\n\n");
            } else {
                // this means device screen is off, and is locked
                Log.i(TAG, "screen is locked\n\n");        
            }

        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
            if (LockScreenHelper.isScreenUnlocked(getBaseContext())) {
                // this means device screen is on, and is unlocked
                Log.i(TAG, "screen is unlocked\n\n");
            } else {
                // this means device screen is on, and is locked
                Log.i(TAG, "screen is locked\n\n");                   
            }
        }

        if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "screen user is present - on and unlocked");
        }
};
```

2) You can use this helper class to determine the screen states at any time:

```
/**
 * Decides what state the lock screen is in.
 * Logic adapted from chromium open source project:
 * https://github.com/crosswalk-project/chromium-crosswalk/blob/master/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/IntentHandler.java
 */

public class LockScreenHelper {
  private static final String TAG = 
  LockScreenHelper.class.getCanonicalName();

  /**
   * Determine if the screen is on and the device is unlocked;
   * i.e. the user will see what is going on in the main activity.
   *
   * @param context Context
   * @return boolean
   */
  public static boolean isScreenUnlocked(Context context) {
    if (!isInteractive(context)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "device is NOT interactive");
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "device is interactive");
    }

    if (!isDeviceProvisioned(context)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "device is not provisioned");
        return true;
    }

    Object keyguardService = context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    return !((KeyguardManager) keyguardService).inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
}

/**
 * @return Whether the screen of the device is interactive (screen may or may not be locked at the time).
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static boolean isInteractive(Context context) {
    PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        return manager.isInteractive();
    } else {
        return manager.isScreenOn();
    }
}

/**
 * @return Whether the device has been provisioned (0 = false, 1 = true).
 * On a multiuser device with a separate system user, the screen may be locked as soon as this
 * is set to true and further activities cannot be launched on the system user unless they are
 * marked to show over keyguard.
 */
private static boolean isDeviceProvisioned(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (context == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (context.getContentResolver() == null) {
        return true;
    }

    return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVICE_PROVISIONED, 0) != 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                if (pm.isInteractive() && pm.isScreenOn() && keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked() && keyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()) { //do your stuff }
```

Comment: I am voting to close this. The question has been answered 10 years ago. And you are just duplicating it.