# Detecting when screen is locked

Tags: android, screen

I've seen a couple of posts on here on how to check if the screen is locked, but none of it has been working for me. It all detects if the actual screen is off or not (not if it's locked).

I have a game in which music plays. When the lock button is pressed, it continues to play. I originally had the music stopping in `OnStop`, but the application would restart after getting locked, so the music would eventually start up again.

Then, I added `KeyboardHidden|orientation` to the manifest. This makes it so it doesn't restart the app, but `OnStop` doesn't seem to get called anymore.

I've tried using `PowerManager` to see if the screen is on/off, which works, but doesn't help. (I can get the music to stop there, but as soon as you hit the lock button again, the music starts right back up)

Comment: [This recent post on the android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html) seems to be somewhat related to your problem. Not sure if it solves this, so I just throw it in here in case you missed it. See if it contains any useful information for you.

Comment: Thanks, it is related, however, I'm struggling to figure out how to actually use the onfocuschanged method.

Comment: Hey @Ryan. How about letting us know via comment or accept if either of these solutions worked for you. I'm curious about the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if user is on lock screen from service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044868/how-to-tell-if-user-is-on-lock-screen-from-service)

Comment: Any app playing music should consider whether it is a good idea to continue once its `View` is not in the foreground any more, regalrdless of whether or not the device is locked, the user choosing a different app to be displayed in the foreground, the system to display a shutdown notice, or whatever. So chances are you're actually asking for the wrong solution.

Answer (score 112):

There is a better way:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

No need for broadcastRecievers, permissions or anything similar.

Note: It doesn't work when user has set his/her screen lock to none
in settings-->security-->screenlock-->none

Comment: Could you please tell me how I get the variable "context"?

Comment: @FiReTiTi, you pass it in to the function or you can the code from a class that has a `Context`....

Comment: How do you listen to this on an ongoing basis?  In a Timer?

Comment: `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()` method was deprecated in API level 28. Use `isKeyguardLocked()` instead, which is available since API Level 16.

Comment: inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode is deprecated in API level 28. Use isKeyguardLocked() instead. Please refer https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/KeyguardManager

Answer (score 32):

This link might be helpful to others for two things at one place.

Check if the Device is Locked Or Not:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean isPhoneLocked = myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

(Note: above method doesn't work if `screenlock` is set to `none` in `settings-->security-->screenlock`.)

Check If Device is Awake or in Sleep Mode:(for Sdk Version > L Preview < Sdk Version)

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
isScreenAwake = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20? powerManager.isScreenOn():powerManager.isInteractive());
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how I get the variable "context"?

Comment: @FiReTiTi, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android ... cmon man....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to precise that I work with Appium, so I don't have a direct access to the phone.

Comment: I think that for checking if device is locked, you should use :
`isPhoneLocked = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN && myKM.isKeyguardLocked) || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN && myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
`

Comment: I guess @androiddeveloper is right. `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()` method was deprecated in API level 28. Use `isKeyguardLocked()` instead, which is available since API Level 16.

Comment: Isn't there a way to have a callback instead? Do live wallpaper apps really query this all the time?

Answer (score 17):

The Above solution is correct but when i get output it gave me an output locked  when screen off and and locked when screen on but doesn't gave unlock output when i unlocked device after putting pattern for unlock.
So Here is my solution.

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {

     final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
    /** System Defined Broadcast */
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

    BroadcastReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String strAction = intent.getAction();

            KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if(strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT) || strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)  )
                if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
                {
                    System.out.println("Screen off " + "LOCKED");
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println("Screen off " + "UNLOCKED");
                }

        }
    };

    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, theFilter);
}
```

after that this will give me output like

```
I/System.out:LOCKED 
when i off the mobile screen
I/System.out:LOCKED
when i on the mobile screen
I/System.out:UNLOCKED
when i unlock the mobile after pattern lock
```

Comment: Instead of `if(strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT) ...`, use `if(theFilter.matchAction(strAction)`

Answer (score 14):

Taken from this link: https://gist.github.com/Jeevuz/4ec01688083670b1f3f92af64e44c112

```
/**
 * Returns true if the device is locked or screen turned off (in case password not set)
 */
public static boolean isDeviceLocked(Context context) {
    boolean isLocked = false;

    // First we check the locked state
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    boolean inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode = keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();

    if (inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode) {
        isLocked = true;

    } else {
        // If password is not set in the settings, the inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() returns false,
        // so we need to check if screen on for this case

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            isLocked = !powerManager.isInteractive();
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            isLocked = !powerManager.isScreenOn();
        }
    }

    Loggi.d(String.format("Now device is %s.", isLocked ? "locked" : "unlocked"));
    return isLocked;
}
```

Comment: this solution worked fine for me after i changed:
 boolean inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode = keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
 to 
 boolean inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode = keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked();

Comment: I tried this on Chromebook but it's not working, is there any other Workaround for Chromebook?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `KeyguardManager` class to check if the screen is locked or not. Below is the code snippet written in Kotlin.

```kotlin
val keyguardManager: KeyguardManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager

if (keyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked) {
   // device locked logic goes here 
} else {
   // device unlocked case
}
```

Comment: This soultion works fine, but `isDevicesLocked()` is deprecated, you can use this code in `onStop()` method and instead of using `isDeviceLocked()` use `isKeyguardLocked()`

Answer (score 3):

The Below code shows if the screen is locked or not.

```
 private void checkPhoneScreenLocked(){
        KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if( myKM.isKeyguardLocked()) {
            System.out.println("Phone is locked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Phone is not locked");
        }
    }
```

[image]

***DrawBack:-We can check the phone is locked or not.only if the user has selected the any security patters other than none.***

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
    /** System Defined Broadcast */
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    BroadcastReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String strAction = intent.getAction();

            KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

            if (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
            {
                if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Screen off " + "LOCKED");
                } else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Screen off " + "UNLOCKED");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, theFilter);
}
```

The above answer from @Shaul Rosenzweig combined with the other post available to detect screen on and off status. I tested this solution on Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini and worked well for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the screen locks X seconds after the screen is turned off.

Comment: Sorry @Sam it didn't work out for you. But, this does work in my case.

Comment: Well, if the phone doesn't lock until 5 seconds *after* the screen locks, your code won't detect the lock screen until the phone's screen is turned on. Not necessarily a big deal. :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "5 seconds *after* the screen turns off"

Answer (score 0):

Luv Kumar's answer works but it only registers when user explicitly locks the screen (by pressing the lock button). Besides that, I want my app to tell when screen goes off (e.g. screen timeout) just did that:

Just added another option to myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()

```
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() || (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyguardManager.isDeviceLocked to detect if the device is currently locked and requires a PIN, pattern or password to unlock.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager#isDeviceLocked()

```
fun isDeviceLocked(context: Context): Boolean {
    return (context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager).isDeviceLocked
}
```