# live wallpaper recognizing if shown on lockscreen

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm toying with the idea of making a live wallpaper for my lockscreen. As it stands, I've only just discovered that you can have a live wallpaper on the lockscreen if you also have it on your regular home screen... so I decided to look into making my own.

I'd like to have my wallpaper show the date, time, and next few upcoming events in my calendar... but I don't want these elements to show if I'm not on my lockscreen.

Is it possible to programatically determine if the phone is unlocked and not show the text? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

According to: [Detecting when screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317331/detecting-when-screen-is-locked)

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager)  
context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
     //it is locked 
} else {
     //it is not locked
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into that. This will be my first time programming anything for Android.

Comment: This is a query though. Isn't there a way to have a callback instead? Do live wallpaper apps really query this all the time?