# Music turn off when screen does so

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I want my app's music to turn off when user turn off the screen.
I bet there is a very simple line of code to achieve this, but I haven't found it yet. Please help me, have a good day :)

Comment: I think it'll help you :
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317331/detecting-when-screen-is-locked>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `OnPause()` method of your activity. And, stop your music here like `mediaPlayer.stop();`.