# How Enable/Disable Accessibility Service When Lock/Unlock Screen in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-service, accessibilityservice

I created an accessibility service and made a window (using WindowManager) in fun onServiceConnected(),
So i want to show a widget when the screen is locked and hide it when the screen is unlocked
I try : `val keyguard = this.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager`
and that make the widget didn't show when the user want it on unlocked screen.
I  tryied also `BroadcastReceiver()` by register/unregister it `onCreate()/onDestroy()` of AccessibilityService class, but `stopService()` in `fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?)`
not working, and i tried kill the process of AccessibilityService in `BroadcastReceiver()` but not working (the process starts again after is killed)
Pleaese help me !
the goal is : show a widget when the screen is locked and hide it when the screen is unlocked programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45100001/15772513
I put it on the Accessibility Service class and call `disableSelf()` when the screen is unlock, and call that function in OnCreate() of AccessibilityService class.

I hope this will help you.