# Check if screen is unlocked

Tags: android

How can I check if the screen is unlocked (E.i. Turned on and not on lockscreen)?

PS. I'm not looking for the unlock event, which I know can be retrieved with an AdminDeviceReceiver, but I'm looking for an executable code that will return a boolean telling me whether or not the screen is unlocked.

Comment: for screen On/Off you can use the Screen On/Off broadcast

Comment: yes thanks, but I need to know if the screen is unlocked

Comment: not sure but you may try to catch the touch screen event for device, it you can that means device is unlocked so been used

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the screen is locked in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002032/how-to-find-the-screen-is-locked-in-android)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try with this:

```
   KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) сontext.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
   if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() ) {
        // it is locked
   } else {
        //it is not locked
   }
```

Taken from: [Detecting when screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317331/detecting-when-screen-is-locked)

Also same answer : [How to tell if user is on lock screen from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044868/how-to-tell-if-user-is-on-lock-screen-from-service)

Answer (score 4):

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if( keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                System.out.println("~~~SCREEN LOCKED~~~");
            } else {
                System.out.println("~~~SCREEN NOT LOCKED~~~");
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

!mKeyguardManager.isDeviceLocked()

Comment: This method added in API Level 22.

Answer (score 2):

Check the Screen Off State in your onPause Method using Power Manager

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    // If the screen is off then the device has been locked
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

    if (!isScreenOn) {

        // The screen has been locked 
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per google Doc `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode` is Deprecated. Instead of You can use below method for phone is wake up or not.

```
private boolean isPhoneIsLockedOrNot(Context context) {
        boolean isPhoneLock = false;
        if (context != null) {
            KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if (myKM != null && myKM.isKeyguardLocked()) {
                isPhoneLock = true;
            }
        }
        return isPhoneLock;
    }
```