# Detect unlock of Android phone in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, unlock

I'm trying to detect the unlock of the phone with the app in background.

I'm registering a receiver with registerReceiver method to detect the unlock of the phone, and apparently it only works as long as the context used is alive so I used the application context :

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I want to know how long I can expect this receiver to work when the user leave my application and does not use it (so when is the application context killed).

I firstly wanted to use the ACTION_USER_PRESENT in the manifest but this need for read_phone_state permission (and it would be difficult to explain to the user why the app need to make calls...).

Comment: Try from this ....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224637/a-way-to-get-unlock-event-in-android  
OR
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: these are for when the app is in foreground, I have edited my title

Comment: Ok then go through this link ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139125/is-there-a-way-for-an-android-service-to-detect-when-the-device-is-locked