# Is there any other methods or functions to detect whether screen is locked?

Tags: android

I am working on a drone app where I need to land the drone when the phone screen in locked. I have tried KeyguardManager but its deprecated. Are there any other functions or methods which I can use?

compileSdkVersion 29

buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

minSdkVersion 15

targetSdkVersion 29

I have already included `onPause` method in my code

```
@Override

    protected void onPause() {

        // Code to land
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: This might helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170563/android-detect-phone-lock-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can determine whether screen is off or not by using PowerManager . like follow .

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
```

although you might see something like this insted `pm.isInteractive()`

```
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

which depracted in api 21 . i hope this work . 
for more detail you can visit documentation here . [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn%28%29)