# Android detect lock Unlock event on Chromebook

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I want to detect the Chromebook lock, Unlock event. I am using Foreground service and register Broadcast to detect Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT. Only getting Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF broadcast but not getting Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT broadcast on Chromebook.

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForeground()

        intentFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
        intentFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)


       //other code

    }

class XYZBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {

        val action = intent.action

      
        if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT == action) {
        
        } 
        else if (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF == action) {
            
        }

        else if(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON == action){
            
        }
    }
```

I am trying lots of methods from [Android detect phone lock event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170563/android-detect-phone-lock-event), [A way to get unlock event in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224637/a-way-to-get-unlock-event-in-android), [Android - detect phone unlock event, not screen on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on) but nothing works for Chromebook.
Is there any other way to detect lock, Unlock events on Android Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

The information you're referring to may be outdated ...

Since API level 26 you won't receive this implicit broadcast on regular Android either:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: I am not declared this in manifests, already explicitly registering Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT with Context.registerReceiver(). Its working fine in Google Pixel Android 11 but not working on Chromebook.

Comment: As the documentation reads: "Even though these implicit broadcasts still work in the background, you should avoid registering listeners for them." ...likely because there is no guarantee for the broadcast to happen.