# Implementing a BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifext.xml File

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I am trying to use a BroadcastReceiver in Android (using the manifest) and just had a quick question.

So far I have this...

```
<receiver android:name=".Listener"
  android:label="testRecv"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true"
  android:process=":recovery">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But when I install the apk on a test device or emulator, nothing is happening what I turn on my screen. Here is the code for the Listener class...

```
public class Listener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "hey", 10);
            t.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am never seeing the toast get fired off (as a test).

Is there something I am missing? I never used Context.registerReceiver() because I declared the  in the manifest, so I though I didn't need to.

The most confusing part about this whole thing is the  and the documentation isn't that helpful for it. Can anybody just help me understand this stuff?

Comment: You do not need `android:exported="true"`, as any `<receiver>` with an `<intent-filter>` is automatically exported. You do not need `android:process=:recovery`, because Android applications should not be creating multiple processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See CommonsWare's reply in [Android - how to receive broadcast intents ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off)

Comment: Interesting, so the manifest created receivers only work for certain types of events?

Comment: @Roflha: They work for most. Some, though, they do not, because Android does not want to start up a whole bunch of processes at once.

Comment: Do you know if there have been any lists published to tell which ones work for which?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "hey", 10);
            t.show();
        }
```

You don't need the if statement