# how to handle sleep mode enter in android?

Tags: android, handler, sleep

I didn't find it anywhere, how can I handle entering sleeping mode in android? I want to do something when android device entered to the sleep mode? Is this possible or is there anyway to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make this by using BroadCastReceivers for system-calls (wakeup/sleep)

[Android - how to receive broadcast intents ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off)

Comment: Technically, these are not related to sleep mode. The device may stay awake for a bit after `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is broadcast. Similarly, the device may be on without the screen being on. However, they *are* the closest broadcasts related to "sleep mode" events.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I handle entering sleeping mode in android?

Generally, you don't. There is nothing you need to do related to sleep mode.

> I want to do something when android device entered to the sleep mode?

I certainly hope not.