# BroadcastReceiver for screen lock not being triggered

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to turn the GPS location updates off when the screen locks. Having read the answer to this question [Android - how to receive broadcast intents ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off)

I've written some code to implement a BroadcastReceiver but it's not working when the screen goes off.

I've registered a BroadcastReceiver in my code with

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter();
    iFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
    iFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
    registerReceiver(screenStatReceiver, iFilter);
```

and the receiver itself is just a stub for now:

```
    public BroadcastReceiver screenStatReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Log.d("BCAST_TAG", "Got broadcast");         
       String action = intent.getAction();

       }
};
```

and in the manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Any ideas as to why it's not being triggered when I debug it on my phone?

Comment: You are registering the reciever in the OnResume method. Why dont you register it in the onCreate() so you can have persistent "listening"?

Comment: i m registering in onCreate but i m not unregistering it

Comment: its throwing error i want to detect screen on changes how will i

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, you have to create a infinite service, which is registering a local broadcast receiver for these intents. If you do this way, then your app will look for screen off but make sure you have to make service which will always running in background like reboot receiver

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the reciever in the `onResume()` method. Why dont you register it in the `onCreate()` so you can have persistent "listening"?

In this case you are listening for changes only after the activity is resumed.