# Why my BroadcastReceiver doesn't work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to learn to use Android BroadcasReceiver. 
I wrote this code but It doesn't work... I tryed for example to change the Time etc...
What is it wrong?

I added in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastreceiverspike.Broadcast" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My simple BroadcasReceiver:

```
    public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Log.d("BROADCAST", "It worked");
           Toast.makeText(context, "BROADCAST",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

My Main Activity (default main Activity)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714731/broadcastreceiver-for-screen-lock-not-being-triggered did you check

Comment: thanks it works. I added my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved!

"unlike other broad casted intents, for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON you CANNOT declare them in your Android Manifest! I’m not sure exactly why, but they must be registered in an IntentFilter in your JAVA code"

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".Broadcast" >
        <intent-filter>                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Main Activity Class

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // INITIALIZE RECEIVER
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new Broadcast();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}
```

}

My broadcast receiver

public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static String TAG = "BROADCAST";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED))
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "BROADCAST Cambio di orario");
        Toast.makeText(context, "BROADCAST Cambio di orario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        Log.d(TAG, "BROADCAST Screen OFF");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Screen OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        Log.d(TAG, "BROADCAST Screen ON");
        Toast.makeText(context, "BROADCAST Screen ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The documentation may have some error, I've been cracking my head for two days, and I discovered that with the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, my broadcast would work! (tested from 4.3 to 5.1) , see my answer and code below, it doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) about broadcast receivers.

**Update:**
I'm not sure you're using this tutorial, because there are lots of useful stuff in this tutorial, like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
        new IntentFilter("my-event"));
    }

    // handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Unregister since the activity is not visible
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

In other words, you've created a custom `broadcast receiver class`, but you haven't used it.

And also please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off).

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the needed premissions?

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"

This is a receiver to handle when screen is off or on or locked:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
    {   



    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    {


    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
    {

    }

}
```

}
this is the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />        
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: why did you add android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT? I don't use it

Comment: i wanted to know when the lock screen is up. and then i displayed a picture. since i didnt want to leave it there forever. i needed to know when the user is present.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it (tested on 4.3 and 5.1). I WAS able to declare "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" inside the manifest, as long as you have the READ_PHONE_STATE permission, it is OK!! My mini app consists of a Broadcast receiver that reacts to the screen ON/OFF state, and runs a background service that does continuous voice recognition. If the screen is off, the recognition is turned off. Here is the code, enjoy: MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> <receiver android:name="classes.VoiceLaunchReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

BROADCAST RECEIVER:

```
public class VoiceLaunchReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {     
        Intent service = new Intent(ctx, VoiceLaunchService.class);
     //   service.putExtra(action, true);
        Log.i("joscsr","Incoming Voice Launch Broadcast...");  

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.i("joshcsr", "************\nCSR Resumed (BC)\n************");
            ctx.startService(service);
            }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("joshcsr", "************\nCSR STOPPED by SCREEN (BC)\n************");
            ctx.stopService(service);  
            }
        }  
}
```

As you can imagine, my USER_PRESENT broadcast receiver is not registered anywhere else. I do register ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ON in the onCreate method of my service, who was triggered by my receiver.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Register screen ON/OFF BroadCast
    launcher=new VoiceLaunchReceiver();
    IntentFilter i=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);               
    registerReceiver(launcher,i);
    Log.d("joshcsr","VoiceLaunch Service CREATED"); 
    }
```

Finally I unregister the screen on/off in the onDestroy() of my service:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(launcher);}
```