# Xiaomi MIUI keeps killing my background application

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui

I'm trying to make an application that, on ring, will identify a phone number from an internet database. No matter what I do, MIUI (In Redmi Note 8T Android 11) eventually kills my application after a while and a notification of the phone state change is not received.

Following advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background) and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467505/why-my-broadcastreceiver-doesnt-work) and my manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

and in `onCreate`:

```
 ComponentName onBootReceiver = new ComponentName(getApplication().getPackageName(), BootReceiver.class.getName());
    if(getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(onBootReceiver) != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED)
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(onBootReceiver,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and my service receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    telephony.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}
```

and my boot receiver:

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

```
    if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

and also, in MIUI preferences, I 've set the app to 'auto start', remove all battery restrictions and enabled all manual permissions MIUI has in the preferences for this app.

What else can I do?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: From what I know MIUI does not respect any flags.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ these method(s) for avoid getting your application killed by MIUI:

```
- App pinning from the recents menu 
- Turn off MIUI Optimizations from developer options in settings
- Enable Autostart, Goto app settings and in battery saver > No restrictions, Allow access to all the required permissions (always)
- Change MIUI Power Management options
```

Go through https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi for more information on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the lock button in the app/task switcher ? You could also try the memory optimization settings 'Developer options' (if they are still present): https://s.kaskus.id/images/2018/06/11/521121_20180611073055.png

If nothing else works you could also add a background service to the app...

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem on phones:

- `Redmi 7A` with `Android 10, MIUI Global 12.5.2 QCMRUXM`
- `Redmi 4A` with `Android 7, MIUI 10`.

MIUI kept closing [Telegram-SMS](https://github.com/telegram-sms/telegram-sms) background service when a phone is not connected to a charger.

Turning off `MIUI Optimizations` option did not help.

Turning off `Power Detector` app by:

```
adb shell
pm disable-user com.xiaomi.powerchecker # Power Detector
#Package com.xiaomi.powerchecker new state: disabled-user
```

also did not help.

The following advice helped to solve the problem:

> Go to Security app > tap settings (gear on top right) > Boost speed >
> Lock apps > Lock the app you need to keep running. This replaces the
> "padlock" icon (App pinning from the recents menu) that no longer is visible in MIUI 12.

Source: [Stop killing my apps Xiaomi!!](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/pz2e3i/stop_killing_my_apps_xiaomi/)

---

`MIUI Optimization` toggle is hidden in `Developer options`. To make it visible need to tap several times on `Reset to default values` option that almost at the bottom of `Developers options`. I did not notice that this option actually resets something. `MIUI Optimization` toggle will appear at the bottom of the list of options. [Source](https://piunikaweb.com/2021/04/19/miui-optimization-missing-in-developer-options-try-this-workaround/)

---

According to `logcat` log `Telegram SMS` app was being killed by `Power Checker` (when the app was not locked in recents menu):

```
01-06 10:50:15.716  4344  4652 W PowerChecker.Controller: autoKillApp, calling ProcessManager uid = 10289, pkg = com.termux
01-06 10:50:15.716  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: Kill reason AutoPowerKill from pid=4344
01-06 10:50:15.829  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: AutoPowerKill: kill com.termux Adj=200 State=5
01-06 10:50:15.830  1580  2093 I ActivityManager: Killing 13234:com.termux/u0a289 (adj 200): AutoPowerKill
01-06 10:50:15.875  4344  4652 W PowerChecker.Controller: autoKillApp, calling ProcessManager uid = 10305, pkg = com.qwe7002.telegram_sms
01-06 10:50:15.876  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: Kill reason AutoPowerKill from pid=4344
01-06 10:50:15.877  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: AutoPowerKill: kill com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:command Adj=200 State=5
01-06 10:50:15.878  1580  2093 I ActivityManager: Killing 23378:com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:command/u0a305 (adj 200): AutoPowerKill
01-06 10:50:15.880  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: AutoPowerKill: kill com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:battery Adj=200 State=5
01-06 10:50:15.880  1580  2093 I ActivityManager: Killing 23348:com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:battery/u0a305 (adj 200): AutoPowerKill
01-06 10:50:15.961  1580  1848 I ProcessManager: remove no clear notification:StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.termux user=UserHandle{0} id=1337 tag=null key=0|com.termux|1337|null|10289: Notification(channel=termux_notification_channel pri=1 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xff607d8b actions=2 vis=PRIVATE))
01-06 10:50:15.968  1580  3450 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.termux/.app.TermuxService in 1000ms
01-06 10:50:15.973  1580  1665 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 13234
01-06 10:50:15.977  1580  4023 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.battery_service in 10992ms
01-06 10:50:15.983  1580  1848 I ProcessManager: remove no clear notification:StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms user=UserHandle{0} id=2 tag=null key=0|com.qwe7002.telegram_sms|2|null|10305: Notification(channel=Chat command  pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))
01-06 10:50:15.984  1580  4019 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.chat_command_service in 20984ms
01-06 10:50:16.650 23510 23510 E ExtAssistant: Error occurred processing removal of StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.termux user=UserHandle{0} id=1337 tag=null key=0|com.termux|1337|null|10289: Notification(channel=termux_notification_channel pri=1 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xff607d8b actions=2 vis=PRIVATE))
```