# Xiaomi, Redmi, Android. Error in Logcat: W PowerChecker.Controller: autoKillApp, calling ProcessManager uid = 10289, pkg = com.termux

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui

Xiaomi Redmi 7A with MIUI 12.5 keeps killing background service / application (`Telegram SMS` and `Termux`) when the phone is not connected to charger. `Logcat` log:

```
01-06 10:45:57.787  1892  1892 I MiuiChargeManager: notifyBatteryStatusChanged:  status: 3 isPlugged: 0 level: 70 wireState: -1 chargeSpeed: 0 m
WiredChargeType: 0 mWirelessChargeType: 0 chargeDeviceType: -1
01-06 10:50:15.716  4344  4652 W PowerChecker.Controller: autoKillApp, calling ProcessManager uid = 10289, pkg = com.termux
01-06 10:50:15.716  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: Kill reason AutoPowerKill from pid=4344
01-06 10:50:15.829  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: AutoPowerKill: kill com.termux Adj=200 State=5
01-06 10:50:15.830  1580  2093 I ActivityManager: Killing 13234:com.termux/u0a289 (adj 200): AutoPowerKill
01-06 10:50:15.875  4344  4652 W PowerChecker.Controller: autoKillApp, calling ProcessManager uid = 10305, pkg = com.qwe7002.telegram_sms
01-06 10:50:15.876  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: Kill reason AutoPowerKill from pid=4344
01-06 10:50:15.877  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: AutoPowerKill: kill com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:command Adj=200 State=5
01-06 10:50:15.878  1580  2093 I ActivityManager: Killing 23378:com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:command/u0a305 (adj 200): AutoPowerKill
01-06 10:50:15.880  1580  2093 I ProcessManager: AutoPowerKill: kill com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:battery Adj=200 State=5
01-06 10:50:15.880  1580  2093 I ActivityManager: Killing 23348:com.qwe7002.telegram_sms:battery/u0a305 (adj 200): AutoPowerKill
01-06 10:50:15.961  1580  1848 I ProcessManager: remove no clear notification:StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.termux user=UserHandle{0} id=1337 tag=null key=0|com.termux|1337|null|10289: Notification(channel=termux_notification_channel pri=1 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xff607d8b actions=2 vis=PRIVATE))
01-06 10:50:15.968  1580  3450 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.termux/.app.TermuxService in 1000ms
01-06 10:50:15.973  1580  1665 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 13234
01-06 10:50:15.977  1580  4023 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.battery_service in 10992ms
01-06 10:50:15.983  1580  1848 I ProcessManager: remove no clear notification:StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.qwe7002.telegram_sms user=UserHandle{0} id=2 tag=null key=0|com.qwe7002.telegram_sms|2|null|10305: Notification(channel=Chat command  pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE))
01-06 10:50:15.984  1580  4019 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.qwe7002.telegram_sms/.chat_command_service in 20984ms
01-06 10:50:16.650 23510 23510 E ExtAssistant: Error occurred processing removal of StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.termux user=UserHandle{0} id=1337 tag=null key=0|com.termux|1337|null|10289: Notification(channel=termux_notification_channel pri=1 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xff607d8b actions=2 vis=PRIVATE))
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why this question was voted down? Please, make an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Need to lock application in Recents menu:

> Go to Security app > tap settings (gear on top right) > Boost speed >
> Lock apps > Lock the app you need to keep running. This replaces the
> "padlock" icon (App pinning from the recents menu) that no longer is
> visible in MIUI 12.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73791704)