# Sharing a variable between many Activities in Android App

Tags: java, android

I am letting my user login to Facebook, Twitter and G+ on my app. After they log in, I want to know that they are logged in on every activity in my app. I am looking to find a way to find this out on each activity. I know you can pas variables from activity to activity using Intent like this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("loginMethod", "facebook");
            startActivity(intent);
```

but this is becoming a hassle to do with 10+ activities. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I recomendo you is to implement shared preferences... going by this way

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putstring("loginMethod","Facebook");
editor.commit;
```

and whenever you want to check the loginMethod value just call the preference value like this...

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());


String loginMethodValue = preferences.getString("loginMethod", "");
```

if you need more assistant I'll be more than happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences.

Here is a good tutorial:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways for doing so.

1. Store it in a singleton
2. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
3. You can extend the Application context

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a Singleton class. The mimimum contents of a singleton are:

1. A static private field of the class type.
2. Other private fields you need ("business" fields).
3. A private constructor.
4. A public static method that returns the only class instance.
5. The business methods you need.

I usually call it *Store*, since it plays the role of a common store for the whole application.
For example:

```
public class Store {
    private static Store me;
    private Facebook fb;
    private Twitter twitter;

    private Store() {
         this.fb=new Facebook();
         this.twitter=new Twitter();
    }

    public static Store get() {
         if (me==null) 
             me=new Store();
         return me;
    }

    public void postInFaceBook(FBPost post) {
        this.fb.post(post);
    }

      ...
}
```

Sometimes you need a context to be shared among activities. In this case, I suggest to pass the application context to the get method:

```
public class Store {
    private static Store me;
    private Facebook fb;
    private Twitter twitter;
    private Context ctx;

    private Store(Context ctx) {
         this.ctx=ctx;
         this.fb=new Facebook();
         this.twitter=new Twitter();
    }

    public static Store get(Context ctx) {
         if (me==null) 
             me=new Store(ctx);
         return me;
    }

    public void postInFaceBook(FBPost post) {
        this.fb.post(this.ctx, post);
    }

      ...
}
```

The use of the Store is simply:

```
public void m(FBPost p) {
    Store.get().postInFacebook(p);
}
```

The first time the store is used, the only instance (which will be shared by the whole application) will be created; the second and next times, the *get* method will return the previous existing instance.

Comment: Thanks for the post, is there an advantage to using this over SharedPreferences as the others suggested? Just curious is all

Comment: For my is easier since I keep the complete control and do as I want. I've never found any drawback to the use of "singletons".

Comment: See also the use of a singleton in: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742776/cant-register-receiver-dynamically/25003574#25003574](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742776/cant-register-receiver-dynamically/25003574#25003574)