# How to show a message when the phone is unlocked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to make an application that would display a message when a user unlocks his/her Android phone. I do not know if this is possible or not.

If anyone has a way to do this, could you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this

In your manifest file write this,

```
receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and MyBroadCastReceiver implementation is like this

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Phone UNLOCKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't register for the SCREEN_ON action in the manifest (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off).

Answer (score 4):

Only **`android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT`** action **`BroadcastReceiver`** is enough to do what you need

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it by registering `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` in manifast as:

```
<receiver android:name=".unlockReceiver">
<intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:priority="90000" android:exported="false">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

and in unlockReceiver show message as:

```
public class unlockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction() != null) {
    if( intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
       Toast msg = Toast.makeText(context,"hello User !!! :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
      }
    }
}
```