# Displaying a Toast notification in Password Unlock Screen

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to display a Toast notification in verifyPasswordAndUnlock() in PasswordUnlockScreen.java whenever a user enters the wrong password. I wrote the following code, and built successfully.

```
 Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, the Toast doesn't appear, because it actually appears in the home screen, which is invisible when the lock screen is on top. I verified this by having another Toast appear when the user successfully logs in, and that Toast only appears in the home screen after the Lock screen disappears

I suspect this is because getContext() returns the home screen's context. How do I get the Lockscreen's context? PasswordUnlockScreen.this doesn't even compile, and mContext and context both have the same problem as getContext()

Comment: maybe using getContext.getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: getContext.getApplicationContext() doesn't work either, it causes a boot loop once password lock is set, due to fatal exception in system process(java.lang.NullPointerException), probably coz PasswordUnlockScreen isn't at the application level.

Comment: Code is too long to paste. Basically I put put the Toast in verifyPasswordAndUnlock() function when it fails the verification.

Comment: this is your response 
[100% tested][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257691/how-to-show-a-message-when-the-phone-is-unlocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said already, the problem is probably not with the Context. I guess you are working with the actual PasswordUnlockScreen source, and not subclassing it? If so, you could try using its `KeyguardStatusViewManager` to display your text:

```
mStatusViewManager.setInstructionText("Invalid password");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on Gingerbread source, and it seems I don't have a KeyguardStatusViewManager, so that line of code doesn't work. Is there any other way of displaying the message in this case?

Comment: I had a look at the Gingerbread source, and it seems they are only using the title text view to show text (`mTitle.setText(...)`). Actually it looks like `KeyguardStatusViewManager` (in 4.0.1 and later) also only modifies an existing TextView, the only difference is that it is reset to its original value after a timeout.

Comment: Yup that seems to be the case. I guess the only way would be to add another TextView in the layout. Trying that now...

Answer (score 0):

All views do have `mContext` field which is initialized to context.

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that PasswordUnlockScreen doesn't have mContext. You can look at the code at https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-ssss-7225/repository/revisions/ceb88d1af25c5412027e8384f056f502900396ef/entry/android/frameworks/policies/base/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PasswordUnlockScreen.java

What's weird is that if I use mContext, it builds, but I get the same problem. Should I add code to initialize mContext to context in the constructor?

Comment: All Views have mContext and PasswordUnlockScreen is a View. so the problem is not because you are using wrong context, I guess the Toast will never be displayed on top of LockScreen, You will have to create your own dialog box which is of type SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW