# Android - Detecting App Resume after screen was locked

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I tell if the current Activity's OnResume has fired because the Application is resuming after the screen was unlocked rather than simply because it was temporarily in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the screen unlock `Intent`:

Implement this `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class UnlockBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(action)){
            // Screen unlocked (Keyguard is gone)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can register and unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` and `onPause()` like this:

```
private final UnlockBroadcastReceiver unlockReceiver = new UnlockBroadcastReceiver();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    registerReceiver(unlockReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(unlockReceiver);
}
```

You can alternatively also register it in the manifest, but that does **NOT** work most of the time.

```
<receiver android:name="path.to.UnlockBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I did indeed need to a BroadcastReceiver and USER_PRESENT action but the only way to get it to fire is to register the receiver in code. Xaver if you update your answer to refer to this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1588267/63286) around code registration I will then mark yours as MY answer

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you test if it is working with the changes I made to the manifest? I am currently not in front of my computer and cannot test it myself.

Comment: I had already tried those two attributes. Did you see what @CommonsWare said?

Comment: Yes I saw, it seems such a `BroadcastReceiver` can only be registered in code. But I will test this more thoroughly when I find the time.

Comment: Xaver did you "test thoroughly"? I want to mark your answer as "the one" but it needs to have the code regsitration in it IMHO

Comment: Yes I tested it, and I found out that registering the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest actually works on some devices with specific Android versions. But I have still no idea why it works on those devices and not on the others.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity or Service:

```
try {
                  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

                  filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

                  BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new receiverScreen();

                  registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
             } catch (Exception e) {

             }
```

receiver code where System inform you if Screen on/off happen:

```
public class receiverScreen extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){

         }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){

         }
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

         }
     }

    }
```

If it IS locked, you can just write to a SharedPreference. Then on your activity's onResume(), you can check for the value of the sharedPreference

In your manifest.xml

```
   <receiver android:name="receiverScreen">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
<action android:name="android.Intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Comment: That is a bad solution. It won't actually work as the OP wants to.

Comment: @harvey_slash - Please note the action should be - `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` in manifest file. The action `"android.Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT"` is incorrect.