# push-button in Android Wear smartwatch

Tags: java, android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

Is there in SDK Android Wear a Class representing a push-button (the push button on the side of the watch)

[image: the push button on the side of the watch]

If it's possible, can I assign a comportment and a method to this push-button, the push-button can be pressed, or clicked, by the user to perform an action.

I found this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button. Html
but I think this Class representing a button widget, not what I want

Comment: The link you provided is for the button UI element. This is only an assumption (hence why this is not an answer), but that button is probably the power button, and the only way to mess with the power button functionality in android is to mess with system files.

Comment: Plus, none of these watches are Android Wear devices. And this question has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568015/can-android-wearable-apps-detect-the-power-button-as-a-keyevent

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way (at this point) to override action for power off button. Also as  CurlyCorvus and Nicolas mentioned you provided link to UI Button (not hardware one) class, and you provided screens with non-Android Wear devices.