# How to detect touch of physical button

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have a wear application. In my app, how do I detect that the user pressed the physical button on the watch?

The documentation says ir cannot be stopped, but I just want a listener.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596321/push-button-in-android-wear-smartwatch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568015/can-android-wearable-apps-detect-the-power-button-as-a-keyevent