# Detect if user is currently present without receiver for ACTION_USER_PRESENT and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

Tags: android, android-powermanager

Is there a way to detect if the user is currently present without listening for the [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)-event and its counterpart [ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)?

I don't like to cache the last event in SharedPrefs, because I can't listen for ACTION_SCREEN_OFF [using a receiver registered in the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off). I want to avoid to implement a service that runs all the time just to get the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF-event. Because that service doesn't run anymore if my app crashes.

[PowerManager#isScreenOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isScreenOn%28%29) or [PowerManager#isInteractive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive%28%29) aren't an option since they return true if the user interacts with the lock screen.

Must support API level >=17.