# Get last broadcasted events

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

Unfortunatly not all events are sticky. So, is there a way to retrieve broadcasted events without an receiver?

I need something like *"ACTION_USER_PRESENT was broadcasted last time 210580 ms after boot."*

Comment: for which broadcast u need that

Comment: for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316859/detect-if-user-is-currently-present-without-receiver-for-action-user-present-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way to retrieve broadcasted events without an receiver?

Only if they were sticky broadcasts, which are being phased out in general. Otherwise, no. Regular broadcasts are ephemeral, being delivered to their matching receivers and then discarded.