# Disable the "Cover Screen to enter sleep mode" gesture on Wear OS

Tags: android, wear-os, gesture, sleep-mode

Consider [this page from Google](https://support.google.com/wearos/answer/6056785?hl=en), examining the point "Sleep or wake your watch", the sub point named "Put your watch in Sleep Mode".

It was brought to my notice, that in rare circumstances people seem to be able to invoke that call for sleep mode without doing so by purpose, just by wearing work protection gear (gloves and long sleeve jackets as it seems).

While I cannot tell how in Googles name these users managed to do this, I was left with the task of disabling this "gesture" to turn on (and off) the sleep mode, because it can mess up data transfers trough open ssh connections in a bad way.
And I cannot find any hint on how to do this. I'm not even sure if this is even considered a gesture or something else.

That app already does run on wake-lock and screen-always on, but that seems to be not enough.

My plan B would be getting the App from going mad by recognizing the enter-the-sleep-mode and its reverse event (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off), but first I want to ask, if there is any way to turn off that feature from inside the App, or by using the Wear OS own settings.

Comment: Based on: https://support.google.com/wearos/thread/8418372?hl=en I would argue that long running processes on WearOS is counter to design (at least originally the watch was a companion to the phone). If the model is root-able perhaps?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, you are right about this, but the Watch does excel as hands-free input device. In order to keep on displaying content and receiving spoken input and process it, we need it to stay lit for the whole process, which is sadly a bit longer than the available time until it turns off its display.